# Strange behavior in Play framework with and without _

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Play 2.4 on Windows 7.
I am newbie in Scala/Play framework, I have a action as below:

```
def delay = Action.async { request =>
    println(new Date() + "-1-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
    val delayed = play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout("Delayed", 10.seconds)
    println(new Date() + "-2-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
    val result = delayed.map{
        println(new Date() + "-3-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
        Ok(_)
    }
    println(new Date() + "-4-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
    result
}
```

I expect the execute order should be 1,2,4,3. However the output is 1,2,3,4 and all in same thread. Then I change the code, replace

```
val result = delayed.map{
    println(new Date() + "-3-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
    Ok(_)
}
```

with

```
val result = delayed.map{ message =>
  println(new Date() + "-3-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
  Ok(message)
}
```

Then the output is 1,2,4,3, and 3 is in different thread.

Could somebody tell me the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's refactor the code a little bit. The first one:

```
// The code between the braces here is just a code block. It is
// executed immediately to calculate the value of mappingFunction.
// That is before the assignment to mappingFunction.
val mappingFunction = {
  println(new Date() + "-3-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
  { message: String => Ok(message) }
}

val result = delayed.map(mappingFunction)
```

The second one:

```
// The code between the braces here is the function that will
// be executed when the future is completed. In which thread it
// will be executed depends on the execution context, and is not
// guaranteed to be the one where mappingFunction is defined.
val mappingFunction = { message: String =>
  println(new Date() + "-3-" + Thread.currentThread().getId)
  Ok(message)
}

val result = delayed.map(mappingFunction)
```